# UnpicklingError: Invalid load key'(heart)'

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

I've been messing around with pickle for some days, trying to apply it in a High Score system in a 'Guess the number' exercise program. I thought that I had grasped the concept correctly, but now this error has appeared and I have no clue as to why.

Here's the relevant code:

```
def EnterHighScore(score,scoresList):
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    newPlayer = player(name,score)
    scoresList.append(newPlayer)
    scoresFile = open('scores','wb')
    pickle.dump(scoresList,scoresFile)
    scoresFile.close()

    for i in scoresList:
        print(i.name + ' - ' + str(i.score))

def CheckHighScores(score):
    try:
        scoresFile = open('scores','rb')
    except:
        scoresFile = open('scores','wb+')

    if not scoresFile.read(1):
        scoresList = []
    else:
        scoresList = pickle.load(scoresFile)
    scoresFile.close()

    if not scoresList:
        EnterHighScore(score,scoresList)
    else:
        for counter,i in enumerate(scoresList):
            if counter == 3:
                break
            if score >= i.score:
                EnterHighScore(score,scoresList)
                break
```

When I run it, the first run through goes fine. That is, when the 'scores' file doesn't even exist. It gets created correctly, the scoresList is created empty and then filled with a player object and it gets dumped into the scoresFile without any errors. But when I try to load the scoresList with the new 'scores' file data, it gives me the following error:

```
UnpicklingError: Invalid load key'(heart)'
```

(heart) standing for an actual heart character.

I've read that others have had this problem, but in those cases they were trying to open the file in different OS's, or had modified the file in some way after pickling but before unpickling. In this case the file hasn't been modified at all, just written to and closed.

I've tried using pickle in other, simpler scenarios, and I haven't caused other errors.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test to see if the file is empty advances the file read pointer past the start of the file:

```
if not scoresFile.read(1):
```

You'll have to seek back to the beginning:

```
if not scoresFile.read(1):
    scoresList = []
else:
    scoresFile.seek(0)
    scoresList = pickle.load(scoresFile)
```

A much better test would be for you to catch the `EOFError` exception that `pickle.load()` throws if the file is empty:

```
try:
    scoresList = pickle.load(scoresFile)
except EOFError:
    # File empty
    scoresList = []
```

Or you could catch the `IOError` when the file doesn't exist:

```
try:
    with open('scores','rb') as scoresFile:
        scoresList = pickle.load(scoresFile)
except IOError:
    scoresList = []
```

and just not open a file for writing here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm rather new with file I/O, and I've been having a hard time remembering the position of the read pointer. Actually remembering its very existance! If you don't mind, I'd like to post your answer in my blog.